# How do I search a column for specific text using the If statement?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get the code to **check if a whole column contains specific text**.
It will always be capitals. There is a lot of code after this line but I only want the code to run if the following condition is met. The code I am thinking along the lines of is as follows.

```
If ActiveSheet.Range("J:J").Text = "GENERAL" Then
```

However this returns nothing, I have tried `Instr()` but to no avail.

What is the right syntax?

Comment: Can you post an example of the text? Also how did you use InStr?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can search within a range;

```
if not ActiveSheet.Range("J:J").Find("GENERAL", MatchCase:=True) is nothing then
    msgbox "found it!"
end if
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments. @Alex K. Thanks this was exactly what i required.

Answer (score 1):

`FInd` has the usuage

`Find(What, [After], [LookIn], [LookAt], [SearchOrder], [SearchDirection As XlSearchDirection = xlNext], [MatchCase], [MatchByte], [SearchFormat])`

You should specify whether matching "GENERAL" should be the whole string (use `LookAt:=xlWhole`), or a partial match (ie to match GENERAL in "GENERAL COMMOTION" use `LookAt:=xlPart`)

Also it's generally best to use a `Range` object (`rng1` below) so you can work with the found object. Although in your case a Boolean test will be enough to either run or not run your further code

**Partial Match**

```
Sub FindPartialString()
Dim rng1 As Range
'find partial match
Set rng1 = ActiveSheet.Range("J:J").Find("GENERAL", , xlValues, xlPart, , , True)
If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "found in " & rng1.Address(0, 0)
Else
MsgBox "no found", vbCritical
End If
End Sub
```

**Whole Match**

```
Sub FindWholeString()
Dim rng1 As Range
'find exact match
Set rng1 = ActiveSheet.Range("J:J").Find("GENERAL", , xlValues, xlWhole, , , True)
If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "found in " & rng1.Address(0, 0)
Else
MsgBox "no found", vbCritical
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the time you have taken to explain Find. I am very new to VBA and the learning curve has been steep. It is very helpful to have things explained and how the syntax works with a particular command. I really enjoy learning more so many thanks again!